# How To ? Display Complete Dashboard on my home page?

Tags: administration, dashboard

I have a dashboard with 4 grids displayed on my home page. It only shows the first row, i.e only 3 of the 4 grids. I am unable to see the 4th grid in the 2nd row 1st column. What can I do to get my dashboard to display all the elements on my homepage? Kindly help.

Attached screen shots 1. [dashboard on hompepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtLQ9.jpg)

[image: Actual Dashboard]

Answer (score 2):

Users can customize their home pages. The generic home page will only display a "snapshot" that shows the top row of the dashboard. If you go to Personal Setup **>** My Personal Information **>** Change My Display **>** Home **>** Customize My Pages (button) **>** You'll arrive at the settings for Dashboard Snapshot Component. You can then select which Dashboard components you want to have displayed on your home page.

Without creating a custom Visual Force home page that creates a place for you to insert the full dashboard, or creating a Custom Dashboard "Snapshot Component" to replace the standard one, I don't believe there's anyway to do what you're asking. Perhaps others may be able to share other suggestions.

Comment: The home page is designed to give an overview of the various pieces of data it provides, not an entire view of everything. As you've stated, you'd need to use Visualforce to show more than just a single row.

Comment: @crmprogdev u mean to say we can have a VF page designed & implemented as a homepage ?

Comment: @sfdcfox dont we have an app in appexchange for this ?

Comment: Forget what I said before. Solution coming...

Comment: awaiting badly, have tried the one mentioned by @sfdcfox, let me know if you have a better solution

Answer (score 2):

Go to Setup > Customize > Home Page > Home Page Components.

Choose the HTML component type, give it a name (e.g. Home Page Dashboard), designate it as a wide component, check the "Show as HTML" checkbox, and copy-paste the following code in the text area:

```
<iframe src="/01Z?isdtp=mn" width="100%" height="500"></iframe>
```

Click save without unchecking the Show as HTML box. Next, go to Setup > Customize > Home Page Layouts, create or edit a layout, add the component to your layout, and save. You'll need to assign the layout to the profiles that should use the new view.

**Edit:** As a side effect, you can also run reports from your home page.

Comment: this will put the complete dashboard & reports page, i particularly want to have a dashboard alone on the homepage not the one you mentioned above

Comment: If you want a specific dashboard, you can use the dashboard ID instead of 01Z. Unfortunately, there's really no other way of doing this without writing some complex JavaScript in a Visualforce page.

Comment: let me try this :)